# Rails Rendering issues with jQuery of i18n translation text with apostrophe inside an yml file

Tags: jquery, rails-i18n, apostrophe

I have a Rails App ( `ruby '2.7.4'` and rails `'6.0.3.3'`), I'm using jQuery

It seams that I'm having issues with apostrophe `'` inside i18n translation file inside a

When I add a translation to a file `content/fr.yml`, for example: `title: "contenu recommandé l'abi"`, it render the string correctly for the concerned `content.html.erb` file.

However when I add a similar translation to an another file `booking/fr.yml`, for example: `content: "l'heure de l'échange."`, it doesn't render the translation properly for the concerned file `booking.html.erb`. The render I have for this translation is: `l&#39;heure de l&#39;échange`

The only known difference to me is that the second file `booking.html.erb` is rendered using javascript (specifically jQuery) to trigger the render of a modal inside the file `booking.html.erb`

I've tried the syntax with `&apos;` and also `title: 'contenu recommandé l''abi'` but with no success until now.

It seems that I'm missing something here but I cannot figure out what is...

How does the rendering of an yml translation file work for i18n within javascript ?

Thanks by advance for your tips and explanations on that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Update! I have finally found a solution using `_html`.
Still not sure about the why though....
Here is the related documentation:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-safe-html-translations.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).